How to configure encrypted SSL keystore password in webapp-runner.jar (embedded tomcat)
I have a Java web application developed using JSP and Servlet, which I run via webapp-runner.jar to launch the WAR file. The webapp-runner.jar provides an option to enable SSL using the --enable-ssl argument, requiring -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore and -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword parameters.
However, I want to pass an encrypted value for javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword rather than a plain text password. It appears that webapp-runner.jar doesn’t support encrypted passwords directly.
Is there any way to achieve this? Any suggestions or workarounds to securely handle the password for SSL configuration would be greatly appreciated.

I would try to use an environment variable first. For instance, set an environment variable ENCRYPTED_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, decrypt it at runtime, and set the System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", decryptedPassword); before initiating the SSL configuration.
If that doesn't work, you can also try creating a small Java class that reads an encrypted password, decrypts it, and then sets it as a system property. This can be integrated into the initialization of your webapp-runner.jar.

Thank you for the suggestion! I tried the first solution using ServletContextListener however it didn't work. Could you provide an example of how to integrate the decryption class into the initialization of webapp-runner.jar? Specifically, how do I ensure the custom logic runs before the SSL configuration is loaded?
